# Angular <p> displayed by *ngFor won't float to the right

Tags: angular, frontend, css-float, ngfor, ng-class

I have this chat in which I'm trying to apply styles to the *"chat-container"*.

The messages are displayed with Angular's `*ngFor` as follows:

```
<p *ngFor="let m of messageArray" [ngClass]="this.currentUser.user._id==m.src?'self pr-3':'otherUser pl-3'">
   {{m.msg}}
</p>
```

The classes applied only have `float:left` or `float:right` depending on the user that sent each message. However, they're always being displayed in the left.

Any suggestions on how to make the messages float to their corresponding side?

Comment: What does your chat container look like? Which styles are applied to it?

Comment: Not much! It's only a card-body. However, I'm testing this with the code that I've provided here and the same issue holds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```
<p *ngFor="let m of messageArray" [ngClass]="this.currentUser.user._id==m.src?'self pr-3':'otherUser pl-3'" class='message'>
   {{m.msg}}
</p>
```

on CSS:

```
.message {
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: row nowrap;
 width: 100%;
}

.self {
 align-items: flex-end;
}

.otherUser {
 align-items: flex-start;
}
```

use *width* on parent div to cover the available space.(you can set the width with px or % is up to you)

Comment: Thanks! I'm not very keen on flexbox as it's a bit overwhelming when coming to media query, but here it did the trick!